# problem with regex

Tags: php, regex

i have this code, but is not working as i expect.

if i write #$% or textwithouterrors the message showed is "correct". So, the regex is not working.

I need to avoid, special characters, spaces and numbers

```
function validateCity($form) {
    if(preg_match("/[\~!\@#\$\%\^\&*()_+\=-[]{}\\|\'\"\;\:\/\?.>\,\<`]/", $form['city'])) {
        echo ("error");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        echo("correct");
        return true;
    }

}

validateCity($form);
```

thanks

Comment: Can you only accept letters? Try /[^A-Z]/i

Comment: side note: city names CAN include spaces, e.g. "Santa Fe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues going on here. The most serious one is that you have syntax errors in your regex: So far, I've noticed `[`, `]`, and `-` all unescaped in your character class. I'm a little surprised the regex engine isn't erroring out from those, since they technically lead to undefined behavior, but PHP tends to be pretty tolerant of such things. Either way, it isn't doing what you think it is.

Before worrying about that, address the second issue: You're blacklisting characters, but you should just use a whitelist instead. That will simplify your pattern considerably, and you won't have to worry about crazy characters like ▲ slipping past your regex.

If you're trying to match cities, I'd go with something like this:

```
if(preg_match("/[^\p{L}\s-]/", $form['city'])) {
    echo ("error");
    return false;
}
//etc...
```

That will allow letters, dashes (think Winston-Salem, NC), and whitespace (think New Haven, CT), while blocking everything else. This might be too restrictive, I don't know; anyone who knows of a town with a number in the name is welcome to comment. However, the `\p{L}` should match unicode letters, so Āhualoa, HI should work.

Comment: @Wire - Sorry, my fault. I left out the backslash in `\p{L}`. Appears to work now (tested on http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/).

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of problems - The hypen `-` should be moved to first or end or escaped otherwise it will be seen as indicating a range. The `[]` have to be escaped.

Try out what you want in some place like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Also you are including lot of stuff in it. Just use something like `\w+` as the match for a valid one rather than looking for an invalid one.

Answer (score 3):

Try reversing your logic. Look for the characters you want, not the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to check if your city name contains any non-letter characters. In that case you can simplify it to:

```
 if (preg_match("/[^A-Z]/i", $form['city'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The character set has an unescaped "]", which looks like the end of the set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[` and `]` inside of your character class.